# how to detect pasteboard item type

Tags: objective-c, nspasteboard

I am trying to identify between three types of objects:

1. if it is a URL of a file
2. If it is a URL of a directory
3. if it is a simple string

up till now, I have just this code, which does not work!

```
NSArray * classes = nil;
            classes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSURL class],
                       [NSAttributedString class],[NSString class], nil];

            NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionary];
            NSArray * copiedItems = nil;
            copiedItems = [pb readObjectsForClasses:classes options:options];
```

Now I try to take the first object of the array copiedItems and try to call "types" property and i get a crash!

Answer (score 3):

Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Articles/pbReading.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey):
You would need to use these pasteboard types, instead of the ones you're using.

```
NSString *NSStringPboardType;
NSString *NSFilenamesPboardType;
NSString *NSPostScriptPboardType;
NSString *NSTIFFPboardType;
NSString *NSRTFPboardType;
NSString *NSTabularTextPboardType;
NSString *NSFontPboardType;
NSString *NSRulerPboardType;
NSString *NSFileContentsPboardType;
NSString *NSColorPboardType;
NSString *NSRTFDPboardType;
NSString *NSHTMLPboardType;
NSString *NSPICTPboardType;
NSString *NSURLPboardType;
NSString *NSPDFPboardType;
NSString *NSVCardPboardType;
NSString *NSFilesPromisePboardType;
NSString *NSMultipleTextSelectionPboardType;
```

There's an pasteboard type for URLs. To distinguish between a file and a folder, you would need to instantiate an NSURL object with the pasteboard data, and find out if it is a directory by querying its attributes.

EDIT:
You also need to consider if the pasteboard data is being put there by your own application or other applications. If it's being put by other applications, I'm not sure the pasteboard types with the classes will work.

I use something like this in one of my projects:

```
supportedTypes = // array with supported types, maybe from the list
NSString *type = [pasteboard availableTypeFromArray:supportedTypes];
NSData *data = [pasteboard dataForType:type];
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I have been scavenging both of these pages for a couple of days... havent had any luck yet! Where did you get this list from?

Comment: List comes from link in my answer (first line, second link). I edited the answer a little bit, should it be helpful

Answer (score 0):

`types` is a method on `NSPasteboard` used to tell you what is available from the pasteboard. So, you shouldn't call it on the items you get back from the pasteboard.

If you're going to request multiple class types, iterate over the response and check the class type of each item, then decide how to interact with it.

Alternatively, decide which class type of data is most useful and make individual class type requests to the pasteboard. If you get a result back, use it and carry on, if not, try the next most useful class type. Look at using `canReadObjectForClasses:options:` to make this easier.

Comment: well, I have just checked. There is a method available on class NSPasteboardItem ... I am going to try out the other idea you have suggested!

Comment: The returned items conform to the `NSPasteboardReading` protocol though and it doesn't have a `types` method.